# Load external json in react-native with fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to load external data with fetch into a react-native mobile app. I have tried with different sources and mostly I get an error message saying the network can't be found.
For instance I have tried with the following two sources.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json (does not work)
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/master/docs/MoviesExample.json (works)

```
componentDidMount(){
    var REQUEST_URL = 'http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json';
    fetch(REQUEST_URL).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.ok) {
            console.log('Response OK');
        } else {
            console.log('Network response was not ok.');
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error);
    })
    .done();
}
```

I am testing in IOS simulator on my MacBook.

I also tried to get json data from my WordPress site, with the latest version of the WP REST API plugin installed. Also this returned a can't find network error.

I am really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 2):

That’s caused by apple’s [security rule](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/), http protocol is restricted(you are sending a http request).

If you need communication in http protocol, there are two solutions(all related to info.plist):

1: Just like what the quick start project does, add the domain name of server:
[image]

2: Add a new rule: “Allow Arbitrary Loads”. don’t forget set the value to “YES”.
[image]